# Hide heading of Naviagation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I want to hide the top of the navigation, what should I do. Thank you for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKZwU.png)

Comment: Hi, you should include more info & include your code. What package do you use for navigation etc.

Answer (score 0):

for your screen in your stack set the option headerShown to false:

```
<YourStack.Screen
        name="YourScreen"
        component={YourComponent}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
```

Comment: Thanh you sir :)